# How to include android module from other git project to mine

Tags: android, git, module

I have two distinct projects (A and B) in git.

```
"A":
+- app
|
+- A.1 module

"B":
+- app
|
+- B.1 module
|
+- B.2 module
```

What I want to do is import the "A.1 module" to the "B" project.

```
"B":
+- app
|
+- B.1 module
|
+- B.2 module
|
+- A.1 module
```

I've tried to add a .gitmodules file into the "B" project and link the "A" project, but what I was able to receive is:

```
"B":
+- app
|
+- B.1 module
|
+- B.2 module
|
+- +- app (A)
   |
   +- A.1 module
```

Comment: One way would be to extract the `A.1 module` folder of project `A` into its own individual repository, and then include that repo as a submodule in both projects.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple when you created modules as a library module. You can convert as a library module by [developer reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library).

Then you have to push your module to GIT. And create a release tag.

Next, you can directly add your module as a dependency into your Application B or some other application easily.

Step-1:  Add Below lines into project-level build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

  }
}
```

Step 2: Reference the library itself in your module-level build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.github.<username>.<github_repository_name>:<release_tag_name>"
```

Now from other Applications, you can access module A.

Otherwise, You can build your module as .aar file. after that, you can import your module in the library folder. You can add the AAR file as a library.